# Segue out of a UINavigationController stack to UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I have `Login.storyboard`:

[image]

The `Login View Controller` has a Segue to a Storyboard Reference and the storyboard `main.storyboard`:

[image]

My LoginViewController class code has a TouchUpInside action handler that programmatically calls the segue to `main.storyboard`:

```
@IBAction func btnLoginTouchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {
        let params = AuthLoginParams(Username: txtFieldUsername.text!, Password: txtFieldPassword.text!)

        AuthLoginRequest.FetchUser(params) { (userModel) -> Void in
            if(userModel.IsAuthorized){
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainStoryboardSegue", sender: nil)
            }else{

            }
        }
    }
```

Now let's look at `main.storyboard`

[image]

So from `Login.storyboard` -> successful login segue -> `Main.storyboard` I am trying to segue "out" of a `UINavigationController` stack and start new/fresh with a `UITabBarController`. Here is a screen shot if I start my app with `main.storyboard` and skip the `Login.storyboard`:
[image]

But if I start my app with `Login.storyboard` and the try using my segue to Stoyboard Reference `main.storyboard` with `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainStoryboardSegue", sender: nil)`

I am still in the Login process UINavBarController stack which I do not want:

[image]

Comment: You can't do what you want with a simple segue.  You need to instantiate your tab bar controller and replace the window's root view controller with it.  This will remove the navigation controller.  Alternatively  you can just hide the navigation bar

Comment: Got it, thanks @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Paulw11's tip in my question comments, he stated that I cannot do what I am trying to with a simple segue, I have to programmtically change the rootViewController and this is the code I came up with, including a transition amimation and all seems to be working nicely:

```
 let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dashboardTabBarController") as! DashboardTabBarController

 UIView.transitionWithView(self.view.window!, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController;
                    }, completion: nil)
```